# How to display query data in a chart? - Django

Tags: django, orm

I am trying to display the query data in the char but I get this error:

TypeError at /estadisticas
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/estadisticas
Django Version: 2.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
    def productos_mas_vendidos(self):
        data = []
        ano = datetime.now().year
        mes = datetime.now().month
        try:
            for p in Producto.objects.all():
                total = Detalle_Venta.objects.filter( â€¦
                    id_venta__fecha_venta__year=ano, id_venta_fecha__venta__month=mes, id_producto=p.id_producto).aggregate(
                        resultado=Coalesce(Sum('subtotal'), 0)).get('restultado')
                data.append({
                    'name': p.nombre,
                    'y': float(total)
                })


▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
ano 2021
data    []
mes 1
p   <Producto: Cuaderno>
self    <store_project_app.views.EstadisticasView object at 0x000001B731FCC700>
```

Comment: This part looks strange:    "....  .get('restultado')" what do you want to get in the query?

Comment: The most sold products during the month